# rails sortable list not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, action, jquery-ui-sortable

I have followed the instructions on http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists for creating a sortable list.

The list drags and drops as it is supposed to, but the sort action is not being fired when the link is released. I have tested this by putting a render :text command into the sort.

No error's appear, it just doesn't fire off the action. I have tried other actions to test it and it doesn't go to them either.

Index:

```
<ul id="tasks">
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <%content_tag_for :li, task do %>
      <span class ="handle"> [drag] </span>
      <%= link_to task.name, task %>
    <% end %>
  <% end  %>
</ul>
<%= sortable_element("tasks", :url => sort_tasks_path) %>
```

Controller:

```
 def sort
    #render :text => 'sorted'
    params[:tasks].each_with_index do |id, index|
      Task.update_all(['position=?', index+1], ['id=?', id])
    end
    #render :text => 'sorted'
    render :nothing => true
  end
```

route:

```
  map.resources :tasks, :collection => {:sort => :post}

  map.resources :tasks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot to sort the order of the tasks for display:

```
@tasks = Task.all(:order => "position")
```